# FreePascal Interfaces: Function that will return "anything"

Tags: function, interface, pascal

I've got an interface called `ILoader`. This is for a type of object that loads resource files.

```
ILoader = interface
    function Load: TObject;
    function FormatName: String;
  end;
```

Quite simple. Now, I want to have multiple types of `Loader`, the TSurfaceLoader, TSoundLoader, TMusicLoader, etc.

The problem is, how do I specify in the `interface` what to return from the functions? The `SurfaceLoader` will load Surfaces, but a `Surface` is not a `TObject`, therefore it won't work.

What do I do? Just ditch the interface all together? (I'll probably expand it, it won't always be this small.)

Comment: A Surface isn't a TObject? Then what is it?

Comment: @Robkennnedy It's a Record, I think.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a precise contract what to expect, so you can't make it variable.

A solution would be to simply typecast:

```
something_of_tsurfaceloader:=TSurfaceLoader(myILoaderIntf.GetObject);
```

Designing out the interface might be better or not, it depends. Those daily choices make life as a programmer interesting :)